# Strange orange border around navigation bar

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Can anyone tell me why theres a strange orange border around my navigation bar, and how to get rid of it? Heres the link to the site: [edit: link removed by me]

Comment: Removal of link makes this a useless posting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's part of your image: http://www.prime.programming-designs.com/wp-content/themes/binaryherov2/images/navibg.png

Comment: FFS, I need to talk to my graphics guy about this :\ Anyway thank you very much.